# Лишние пробелы в русскоязычной подписи графиков ggplot2

Tags: кодировка, r, ggplot2

При построение графика в ggplot2 возникают лишние пробелы возле подписи данных в том случае, когда используются русские символы.

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y =mpg, color = cyl))+
geom_point() +
labs(color = "Русское название") +
theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linetype = "solid", size = 0.7),
      legend.justification = c(1, 1),
      legend.position = c(1, 1),
      legend.title.align = 0)
```

[image: png1]

Хотелось бы устранить этот отступ от правого края в подписи данных. В англоязычной версии такого нет.

[image: png2]

Скрипт сохранен в кодировке CP1251. Настройки кодировки операционной системы:

> "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"

Всевозможные изменения настроек `legend.` функции `theme()` не помогли.

Comment: на Linux все хорошо...

Comment: Еще я заметил, что и при использовании функции plot() появляются такие же пробелы. Система Widows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит очень странно, но все так.
Не решение, но способ обойти (достаточно незаметно):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(color = "Русское\nназвание") +
    theme(
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.position = c(0.05, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0,
        legend.background = element_rect(
            color = NA,
            fill = NA,
            linetype = "solid",
            size = 0.7
        )
    )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]